# Spotify Application artists data scraping

Tags: spotify

i would like to get all artists information like rank,active listeners,followers and increment today details. Is there any possiblity tool to get scraped whenever i want.

Answer (score 2):

The Spotify API has a Get an Artist endpoint that gives you access to things like popularity, images, followers, genres, etc. It is documented here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artist/

A response may look like this:

```
{
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0OdUWJ0sBjDrqHygGUXeCF"
  },
  "followers" : {
    "href" : null,
    "total" : 306565
  },
  "genres" : [ "indie folk", "indie pop" ],
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0OdUWJ0sBjDrqHygGUXeCF",
  "id" : "0OdUWJ0sBjDrqHygGUXeCF",
  "images" : [ {
    "height" : 816,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/eb266625dab075341e8c4378a177a27370f91903",
    "width" : 1000
  }, {
    "height" : 522,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/2f91c3cace3c5a6a48f3d0e2fd21364d4911b332",
    "width" : 640
  }, {
    "height" : 163,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/2efc93d7ee88435116093274980f04ebceb7b527",
    "width" : 200
  }, {
    "height" : 52,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/4f25297750dfa4051195c36809a9049f6b841a23",
    "width" : 64
  } ],
  "name" : "Band of Horses",
  "popularity" : 59,
  "type" : "artist",
  "uri" : "spotify:artist:0OdUWJ0sBjDrqHygGUXeCF"
}
```

You can request additional features in the Web API issue tracker here: https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues